# lsblk size not adding up

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, lsblk

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. when I do `lsblk` size is not adding up.

```
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop1    7:1    0  54.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/558
loop2    7:2    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop3    7:3    0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop5    7:5    0  42.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13831
loop6    7:6    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop7    7:7    0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
loop8    7:8    0  32.5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13640
loop9    7:9    0 247.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/87
loop10   7:10   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2246
loop11   7:11   0  61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1270
loop12   7:12   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2253
loop13   7:13   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
sda      8:0    0   100G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  15.5G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Total sda is 100G but this is not equal to `sda1`, `sda2` & `sda5`. So total ~84G is missing.

No pv, lv or vg .....

```
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# pvs
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# pvdisplay
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# vgs
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# vgdisplay
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# lvs
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# lvdisplay
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca#
```

`fdisk`

```
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x91a4b639

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048  1050623  1048576  512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 33552383 32499714 15.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672 33552383 32499712 15.5G 83 Linux
root@UbunutuTemplate-001:/home/tca#
```

Also, I would like to use unclaimed space to my `/dev/sda5`, how can I?

Comment: output from `fdisk -l /dev/sda` might be more helpful

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: Disk model: Virtual disk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers don't add up because you have unclaimed space at the end of the disk.

You could add another primary partition to this disk to use up the remaining 84G.

Note:

- 209715200 sectors / 2 / 1024 / 1024 = 100G
- 33552383 is the end of the last partition
- 209715200 - 33552383 sectors = 84G
- sda2 is an "extended" partition that contains sda5.

Comment: how can i add unclaimed space to /dev/sdb5?

Comment: @Mohammed be careful as you do this (You can destroy your data) but you can run `fdisk /dev/sda` and it will give you back a prompt where you can type `n` (meaning add new partition). It will then prompt you to choose the partition number, first and last sector (you can leave the default values by just pressing enter). And then you can type `w` to write to the disk and quit fdisk. Do this at your own risk

Comment: What AbdelhakimAKODADI describes will create a new partition.  Expanding sda5 is much more difficult.  The answer from dominix explains how to grow it instead of making a new one.  (I'm assuming sdb5 is a typo.)

Answer (score 2):

to use your unused space extend it with `parted`.

install parted if you do not already have it.
you need to extend the sda2 first because it is an extended, then extend sda5

```
parted /dev/sda resizepart 2 99GB
parted /dev/sda resizepart 5 99GB
```

alternatively you can use

```
growpart /dev/sda 2
growpart /dev/sda 5
```

Now just resize your filesystem. if it is ext4 use

```
resize2fs /dev/sda5
```

(it may require that you fsck first... )